# Execute python3 script using for loop in command prompt

Tags: python, command-line-interface

Folder stucture->

[image]

Problem stmt- I am trying to run the setup files from command prompt.

Steps I m following-

1. cd Parent
2. set pkgs=Child1,Child2,Child3
3. for %P in (%pkgs%) do cd %P && python setup.py && cd ..

Expected output-

> It should run the files.

Current output-
It prints the lines as is.

> cd Child1  && python setup.py && cd ..

> cd Child2  && python setup.py && cd ..

> cd Child3  && python setup.py && cd ..

Comment: Since this is a question where the code you're trying to fix is a shell script, you should really tag your shell, not [tag:python].

Answer (score 0):

Use sh,

```
cd ......./Child1
python3 setup.py &
cd ......./Child2
python3 setup.py &
cd ......./Child3
python3 setup.py &
```